# How to find out if I'm using a theme in my vaadin application

Tags: pom.xml, vaadin7

I've just created a vaadin application, the simplest one you can create, and I was wondering, how do I find out if I have a theme in it and which one it is? The reason for that is that I'm deploying my application to Jenkins and it doesn't like something in my pom.xml file, which I commented out:
compile-theme</goal> -->
With this commented out it works but I need to now whether it is safe to do so. I know that if I don't have a theme it's OK to do it, but I'm trying to find out whether I do have a theme. My understanding is that a theme should be inluded to the pom.xml file under  but I can't find any there:

```
<properties>
        <vaadin.version>7.6.5</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.2.3.v20140905</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

Does it mean that I'm not using any theme?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the theme for a Vaadin application can be done with the `@Theme` annotation on your `UI` class:

```
@Theme("demo")
public class DemoUI extends UI {
...
```

The theme is not configured in your build configuration (`pom.xml`).

If you do not specify a theme to be used anywhere, Vaadin will transparently use a default theme (`reindeer` or `valo`). So every Vaadin app will use a theme even if it is not specifically configured.

If you want to check the theme which is currently used by your Vaadin application, you can do so using the [debug mode](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-debug.html). Open the debug window and activate the general info tab. There you can see the currently active theme, the used widget set, the current Vaadin version and more.

Regarding the `compile-theme` goal in your build configuration: It is safe to comment this goal out as long as you don't use a custom theme which needs compiling. If you use one of Vaadin's built-in themes, you don't need this goal to be active. Check the documentation about [Vaadin themes](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html) for details.